# How to create a database in couchdb programatically?

Tags: ajax, couchdb

I am able to create a database using `futon or curl` command but I am trying to create a database by getting the database name from the user. I had a textbox and a button when user types the database name and on clicking create db i am calling a ajax function to access the couch db. I am dont really know how to create a database on button click. I could get example like task list to insert edit and update but I am not able to create a database using ajax. 
I tried with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#adddb").click(function(){
                var dbname = $("#dbname").val();
                 $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: DATABASE,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: dbname
             });
            });
        });
<input type="text" id="dbname" placeholder="Database Name"> 
    <input type="button" id="adddb" value="Add Db">
```

I am getting this error.

```
PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Is this a way to create a db or I am wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was keep trying this following works fine for me.

```
 $("#adddb").click(function(){
                 dbname = $("#dbname").val();
                 $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: DATABASE+"/"+dbname,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: dbname
             });
```

PUT request helps to create a database as it is in curl PUT command

Answer (score 1):

As the [Doc](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/common.html#put--db) suggests:

Your Request need not contain anything in the body, the request URL should itself contain the dbName

```
var dbName = $("#dbname").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: DATABASE_URL+"/"+ dbName
});
```

Also the dbName should make sure it follows these rules:

- Name must begin with a lowercase letter (a-z)
- Lowercase characters (a-z)
- Digits (0-9)
- Any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and /.

Or follow this RegExp `^[a-z][a-z0-9_$()+/-]*$.`